# return value from json object stored in asyncstorage react-native

Tags: json, react-native, asyncstorage

I've stored a json object inside AsyncStorage, and now i want to retrieve its value.

At the actual code, the value printed is [object Object].

I wish to print the json value nested inside the object.

Any tips?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

    class Inside extends Component {

        render() {
          async function getItem(item) {
            try {
              const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(item).then((val) => {
                return JSON.parse(val);
              });
              return value;
            } catch (err) {
              if(err) {
                throw err;
              }
            }
          }
          return (
            <Text>{getItem('userdata').toString()}</Text>
          );
        }
      }

    export default Inside;
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(getItem('userdata'))` should probably do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you have stringify {email: 'test@test.com'} and store it using AsyncStorage then you can parse the value of email :

```
let value = await getItem('userdata');
return (
        <Text>{JSON.parse(value).email}</Text>
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your class.

Ideally, you do not want functions or direct function calls in your render (especially an async function).

The proper way to do this would be to create that async function outside of render, call the function during the `constructor` or `componentDidMount` lifecycle, send the results to update the components state with setState, and reference that state in the render.

This would be more or less...the **React** way:

```
class Inside extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      itemString: "",
    }

    this.item = this.getItem('userdata')
  }

  async getItem(item) {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(item).then(val => {
        this.setState({ itemString: val })
        return JSON.parse(val)
      });
      return value
    } catch (err) {
      throw err
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>{this.state.itemString}</Text>
    );
  }
}

export default Inside
```